# missing logs in aws cloudwatch lambda insights

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda-edge, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I've enabled "Enhanced monitoring" and assign CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy to all my functions, but can't see any info in CloudWatch lambda insights. It just tells me that I didn't enable this feature [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IDPz.jpg).
Could someone please point what should be configured more to get lambda insights working?
thanks.

Comment: were you able to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I turned on Lamda Insights via Enhanced monitoring and had the same problem. This blog also explains how to progress, although the steps are a little vague and took lots of hair pulling over several days to apply:
https://bahr.dev/2021/06/03/lambda-emfile/

TLDR:
First of all, the lambda needs to have run if you want to generate lamda insights. You might not see the information in CloudWatch > Metrics because not all insights are recorded as a metric. (More on that later)

Go to:
CloudWatch > Log Insights (In left pane) > Click the dropdown to the left of the "Browse log groups" button > Select "/aws/lambda-insights"

Run the following query, although you'll need to adjust the time period you're querying over, the value you want to graph (fd_use in this case) and the period you want to aggregate over (10 minutes in this case)

```
# The below allows you to log file descriptors over a 1 day period. Remember to update the period
fields fd_use
| limit 100
 | STATS max (fd_use)  as max_file_descriptors by bin (10m)
```

To view the data as graph
Click the visualisation tab > select "Graph type: Bar"

There are more log insights values that are output in logs but aren't recorded in metrics.
Full list here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Specification.html
To view these, you can run the following query exactly as it is.

```
fields anything
```

Expand any of the rows
Under @message, you'll find the lamda insights values. Those that are recorded as metrics are found in the "Metrics" key value pair

Insights recorded as metrics are available here.
Cloudwatch > Metrics > All Metrics > LamdaInsights > function_name
I don't know much about this section. The insights I needed weren't recorded as metrics

Hope this helps someone